# ¿Solución a error en servicio Oracleagent11g1Agent?

Tags: oracle-11g

Saludos, hoy he estado teniendo problemas con los servicios de Oracle, especificamente el servicio Oracleagent11g1Agent en Windows Server 2003 64 Bits Service Pack 2, intento lanzar el servicio manualmente y me sale este error:

---

### Services

### Windows could not start the Oracleagent11g1Agent on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 2.

### OK

¿A qué se debe y como puedo solventarlo?

Comment: El mansaje te sugiere de revisar el *System Event Log*. ¿Has verificado eso?

Comment: Llevo horas buscándolo... soy más de ubuntu que windows...

Comment: Y google no te ayudo a encontrarlo? sin esa info, solo sabemos que hay un error...

Comment: No... soy muy nuevo en Oracle y más nuevo en windows server... soy más de Postgresql y ubuntu... ahí sí es más fácil encontrar los errores...